# error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall Visualizza::* )(char [])' to 'AFX_PMSG'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

Can someone help me?
I'm doing an MFC application via VS 2010 ultimate.
ps. im new withth c++.
This application is for print on a combox filenames.

this is the .cpp file

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Visualizza, CDialogEx)
    ON_CBN_SELCHANGE(IDC_COMBO1, &Visualizza::OnCbnSelchangeCombo1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// Visualizza message handlers


void Visualizza::OnCbnSelchangeCombo1(char util[20])
{
    std::string s = util;
    LPTSTR x = new TCHAR[s.size() + 1];
    stampa.AddString(x);
}
```

and this is the .h file

```
#pragma once
#include "afxwin.h"


// Visualizza dialog

class Visualizza : public CDialogEx
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(Visualizza)

public:
    Visualizza(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~Visualizza();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG1 };

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg void OnCbnSelchangeCombo1(char util[20]);
    CComboBox stampa;
};
```

Comment: In which line is the error found?

Comment: The proper prototype is `afx_msg void OnCbnSelchangeCombo1()` - no parameter. It would also be very surprising if changing the selection added items to the combo box, so you should probably rethink your approach.

Comment: The error si here ON_CBN_SELCHANGE(IDC_COMBO1, &Visualizza::OnCbnSelchangeCombo1)

Comment: @molbdnilo what can i do?

Comment: Use a function with the appropriate prototype. You probably also should study more and guess less.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm a 17 yo student and my prof gave me this program to do autonomously and I don't know how to go on.

Comment: Unfortunately, this site is not really suited for an "Introduction to MFC for C++ beginners" article. Ask your professor for learning materials. (Personally, I think it's very unfair to ask a C++ beginner to start working with MFC. You need to know quite a bit about C++ if you want to make sense of it.)

Comment: I will, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registering notification handlers is explained in the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class#remarks) section of the `CComboBox` documentation. In particular, the following needs to be followed:

> The parent's function prototype is as follows:
>
> ```cpp
> afx_msg void memberFxn( );
> ```

In other words: Your user-supplied notification handlers cannot take any arguments.

```cpp
void Visualizza::OnCbnSelchangeCombo1(char util[20])
```

would need to be changed to

```cpp
void Visualizza::OnCbnSelchangeCombo1()
```

to make it compatible with the `ON_CBN_SELCHANGE(IDC_COMBO1, &Visualizza::OnCbnSelchangeCombo1)` message map entry.

Comment: And the how to get the newly selected item from the combobox?

Comment: @dia As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class#remarks), you can use `GetLBText`. If you are interested in the selected index, call [CComboBox::GetCurSel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class#getcursel).